# problema para instalar extension mongodb en laravel y ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, composer, extensiones

Necesito instalar el paquete de mongodb [Laravel MongoDB](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) para laravel pero me tira el siguiente error:

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb
```

> Using version ^3.6 for jenssegers/mongodb
>   ./composer.json has been updated
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.0 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.4 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0-beta1, 1.8.x-dev, v1.4.x-dev, v1.5.x-dev, v1.6.x-dev, v1.7.x-dev].
>       - jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.1 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.4 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0-beta1, 1.8.x-dev, v1.4.x-dev, v1.5.x-dev, v1.6.x-dev, v1.7.x-dev].
>       - jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.2 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.4 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0-beta1, 1.8.x-dev, v1.4.x-dev, v1.5.x-dev, v1.6.x-dev, v1.7.x-dev].
>       - jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.3 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.4 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0-beta1, 1.8.x-dev, v1.4.x-dev, v1.5.x-dev, v1.6.x-dev, v1.7.x-dev].
>       - jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.4 requires mongodb/mongodb ^1.4 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.7.0-beta1, 1.8.x-dev, v1.4.x-dev, v1.5.x-dev, v1.6.x-dev, v1.7.x-dev].
>       - mongodb/mongodb v1.7.x-dev requires ext-mongodb ^1.8 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - mongodb/mongodb v1.6.x-dev requires ext-mongodb ^1.7 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - mongodb/mongodb v1.5.x-dev requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - mongodb/mongodb v1.4.x-dev requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - mongodb/mongodb 1.8.x-dev requires ext-mongodb ^1.8 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - mongodb/mongodb 1.7.0-beta1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.8 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - mongodb/mongodb 1.6.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.7 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - mongodb/mongodb 1.5.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - mongodb/mongodb 1.5.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - mongodb/mongodb 1.5.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.3 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - mongodb/mongodb 1.4.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
>       - Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.6 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.6.0, v3.6.1, v3.6.2, v3.6.3, v3.6.4].

Comment: Composer te informa que 'falta la extensión PHP solicitada mongodb en tu sistema'. ¿Puedes confirmar que la extensión está instalada y habilitada?

Comment: si, me tira un listado de extensiones, las cuales con php --ini estuve viendo y estan todas.

Comment: ¿Todas cuáles? `mongodb` tendrías que buscar... Prueba esto: **1.** `php -m` para ver que la extensión está instalada

**2.** `php -i | grep mongo` te mostrará dónde se encuentra mongodb en el archivo ini

**3.** cambia `extension=mongo.so` (si está escrito así) a `extension=mongodb.so`

Comment: hice el paso 1 y no tengo la extension de mongodb. Es eso lo q quiero instalar. Perdon pero no entiendo bien. Ya tengo instalado mongodb y compass pero me faltaria la extension para usar con laravel. Por eso hice "composer require jenssegers/mongodb" y llegue hasta acá.

Comment: Claro, esa extensión de php es requerida por el paquete que quieres instalar (en realidad para usar mongodb en php). Como instalar la extensión depende de varias cosas... Puedes probar primero lo más sencillo que sería instalar la extensión de los repositorios de ubuntu `sudo apt-get install php-mongodb` y luego  `composer require jenssegers/mongodb`   y ver si eso lo resuelve.

Comment: claro, pero hasta ahi es a donde llegué. Al hacer composer require jenssengers/mongodb me tira el error de arriba.

Comment: si, me dice q esta en su version mas reciente. y despues hice el paso dos hasta llegar aca.

Comment: no, al hacer php -m me tira el listado de extensiones pero no tengo mongodb. Y al hacer "php -i | grep mongo" no me muestra nada.
Pero cuando hice  sudo apt-get install php-mongodb me dice q esta en su version mas reciente y composer require jenssegers/mongodb me tira el error arriba comentado.

Comment: Prueba con `sudo phpenmod mongodb`

Comment: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.4
    - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.3
    - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install jenssegers/mongodb v3.6.1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.14.1
    - Installation request for jenssegers/mongodb ^3.6 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.6.0, v3.6.1, v3.6.2, v3.6.3, v3.6.4].

Comment: me dice esto.. y al final 
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Comment: Prueba reiniciando el servidor

Comment: si, ya lo hice tambien pero sigue el mismo problema. me dijeron q tengo q tener una version 1.6 o superior de esta extension.  tenes idea como hacerla ?

Comment: solo hice php --ri mongodb porque los demas comandos no me devuelven nada. Me dice version 1.7.4 y esto no se condice con lo demas. Por lo que estoy viendo es bastante simple hacer la instalacion de la extension pero me sigue trayendo problemas. Capaz el problema viene por otro lado.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ya encontré la solucion. Te comento por si lo necesitas o alguien mas. en composer.json cambié a "jenssegers/mongodb": "4.0.0-alpha.1" porq es la version disponible. Luego hice composer update y despues si, composer require jenssegers/mongodb 4.0.0-alpha.1 para instalar dicha extension.

Comment: Genial, agrégalo como respuesta y márcala como aceptada. Así realmente tendrá mas chance de que alguien más lo lea.

Answer (score -1):

Para usar Laravel con la extensión MongoDB:

> sudo composer require jenssegers/mongodb 3.6 --ignore-platform-reqs

Hay que especificar la versión exacta compatible con nuestra versión de Laravel (en mi caso Laravel 6):

Laravel 4.2.x - package 2.0.x,
Laravel 5.0.x - package 2.1.x,
Laravel 5.1.x - package 2.2.x or 3.0.x,
Laravel 5.2.x - package 2.3.x or 3.0.x,
Laravel 5.3.x - package 3.1.x or 3.2.x,
Laravel 5.4.x - package 3.2.x,
Laravel 5.5.x - package 3.3.x,
Laravel 5.6.x - package 3.4.x,
Laravel 5.7.x - package 3.4.x,
Laravel 5.8.x - package 3.5.x,
Laravel 6.x   - package 3.6.x,
Laravel 7.x   - package 3.7.x,
Laravel 8.x   - package 3.8.x

Comment: Es confuso en final, es entonces ¿una solución?